# Can I sort a column (Character) by last part of a string / value?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a column (character) that has a list of values such as (the prefix refers to the season and suffix a year):

```
Wi_1984,
Su_1985,
Su_1983,
Wi_1982,
Su_1986,
Su_1984,
```

I want to keep the column type and format as it is, but what I would like to do is order the df by this column in ascending season_year order. So I would like to produce:

```
Wi_1982,
Su_1983,
Su_1984,
Wi_1984,
Su_1985,
Su_1986,
```

Using normal sorting will arrange by Wi_ or Su_ and not by _1984 i.e. _year. Any help much appreciated. If this could be done in dplyr / tidyverse that would be grand.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

For a task like this, try doing it by hand with pencil and paper. Try to formulate which steps you need to take in order to complete your task.

Comment: Split into 2 columns, then use `order` as usual: `df1[ order(df1$Year, df1$Season), ]`, we don't need yet another magic function for this.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `parse_number` to get the numeric part and use that in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(parse_number(col1))
```

---

Or if the numbers can appear as prefix, then extract the last part

```
df1 %>%
  arrange(as.numeric(str_extract(col1, "\\d+$")))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can extract the numeric part using `sub` and `order`

```
df[order(as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+)", "\\1", df$col))), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer based on @zx8754 comment, you can do,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 separate(X1, into = c('season', 'year')) %>% 
 arrange_at(vars(c(2, 1)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 2
>   season year 
>   <chr>  <chr>
> 1 Wi     1982 
> 2 Su     1983 
> 3 Su     1984 
> 4 Wi     1984 
> 5 Su     1985 
> 6 Su     1986
> ```